# Django/Python - Collect the data to the right form (Algorithm)

Tags: python, django, algorithm, sorting, django-templates

I have the models like this:

```
Item:
    name
    desc

AttrGroup:
    name
    order

AttrName:
    name
    group.ForeinKey(AttrGroup)
    order

AttrVal:
    value
    attr.ForeinKey(AttrName)
    item.ForeinKey(Item)
```

So I want to compare the attributes of **n** items in the list items_id=[1,3,7,...]

In views, I do something likes this:

```
attrs = AttrVal.object.filter(item__id__in=items_id)
```

and send to the templates. But I'm gonna confusing with the way how to arrange the list for interface.

The templates should like this:

```
<table>
    {% for g in group %}
        <tr class="group_name">{{ g.name }}</tr>
        {% for a in attrs %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ a.name }}</td>
            {% for i in items_id %}
                <td>{{ value of item 'i' }}</td>
            { %endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I think it will have a good solution for this issue. Thanks!

**Update:**
Follow the pretty solution from @Lott, I found out the way how to show the data to templates. I'm using the code likes this:

```
{% for g in groups %}
    <tr class="title_row">
        <td class="group_name" colspan="{{ no_items }}">{{ g.0 }}</td>
    </tr>

    {% for a in g.1 %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ a.attr.name }}</td>
        {% for i in comparing_items %}
            <td>{% if a.item.id == i %}{{ a.value }}{% endif %}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And the it appears:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Attr Name 1</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item 1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Attr Name 2</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item 1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Attr Name 1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My goal is that list the same attribute of items [1,2,3,...] in a same row. The HTML should be like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Attr Name 1</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item 1</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item 2</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item 3</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item n</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Attr Name 2</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item 1</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item 2</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item 3</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item n</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Attr Name m</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item 1</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item 2</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item 3</td>
        <td>Attr Value of Item n</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this for the problem:
http://djangosnippets.org/search/?q=partition%20list

Answer (score 1):

In your view function you can can find the AttrName and AttrGroup for each AttrValue in the `attrs` query set.  You create the *relevant* groups in the view function.  Then you display the details in your template.

```
groups = defaultdict( list )
for a in attrs:
    groups[a.attr.group.order, a.attr.group.name].append( a )

group_list = [ (name[1], groups[name]) for name in sorted( groups.keys() ) ]
```

Your template will look like this

```
<table>
    {% for g in group_list %}
        <tr class="group_name">{{ g.0 }}</tr>
        {% for a in g.1 %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ a.name }}</td>
            {% for i in a.item %} <!-- Yes, you can refer to methods of model objects. -->
                <td>{{ i }}</td>
            { %endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Lott, thanks for the solution. And the result of your way is good but it has some ploblem http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/4701/screenshot20110429at857.png

Comment: @Anh Tran: "some problem"?  Please be more precise in describing the problem.  You might want to **update** the question with the code you actually used and the "some problem" you're having.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Actually, I want to collect the marked attributes(view in the picture) in same line. That's all. Thanks :) http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/4701/screenshot20110429at857.png

Comment: @Anh Tran: "I want to collect the marked attributes"? Please be more precise in describing the problem.   Please **Update** the question to be complete and precise and specific.  The picture isn't really helpful.  Please provide as complete a specification as you can possibly provide.  Also, please **modify** the supplied code to make it work.  You're not obligated to use the code I wrote.  And I won't spend much time debugging your application's details.

Comment: @Lott: Your code works well. But the problem is in templates. Please get understanding via the picture. Thanks alot! http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/4701/screenshot20110429at857.png

Comment: @Anh Tran: "Please get understanding via the picture".  Sorry.  It doesn't make sense to me.  Please explain what is wrong and what should happen by **updating** the question.

Comment: I've updated the question. Please help me some more. Thanks :)